# Get value of previous cell in filtered view in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

[image]

I amd trying to create a formula that will allow me to reference the previous filtered cell of the current view.

I have data formatted as a list of transactions for different products and I would like to filter on product and show the sum of all previous transactions for that product, as of said transaction.

If there was no filter I would do this by;

```
[value of current transaction] + [value of previous sum]


=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN() - 1)) + INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() - 1, COLUMN()))
```

Is there a way to get the row and column relative to the currently filtered / visible cells?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ok_jNU4gdeMrTd2hGKCootUPt1n3Oy2tL8JUX5WzM0/edit?usp=sharing

I hope this illustrates it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a helper column with formula which you need to drag down:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, B6)
```

[image: 0]

and then you can use this formula and hide helper column:

```
={"Total Value Sold"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C6:C="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(C6:C)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(C6:C)))*C6:C*A6:A), SIGN(C6:C))))}
```

[image]

[image: 0]

Comment: In my production data, I have 4400 rows. I get the error "the resulting array was too large".

Comment: try: `={"Total Value Sold"; ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(C6:C2000="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(C6:C2000)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(C6:C2000)))*C6:C2000*A6:A2000), SIGN(C6:C2000))); 
 IF(C2001:C4000="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(C2001:C4000)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(C2001:C4000)))*C2001:C4000*A2001:A4000), SIGN(C2001:C4000))))}` or smaller chunks